# Unsupported SQL Type 1111 when passing String to a VARCHAR field

Tags: java, database, orm, sybase, ibatis

I have been smashing my head against this for a while now.

I am using iBatis with my JAVA code to run Stored Proc residing in Sybase DB.

Stored procedure is expecting some parameters. few of them are declared as `VARCHAR (6)`

So in my iBatis mapping i did the following for those parameters.

```
<parameter property="searchUserId" jdbcType="String" javaType="java.lang.String" mode="IN"/>
```

However, when I do this I get the following error.

```
--- Check the statement (update procedure failed).  
--- Cause: java.sql.SQLException: JZ006: Caught IOException: java.io.IOException: JZ0SL: Unsupported SQL type 1111.
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: JZ006: Caught IOException: java.io.IOException: JZ0SL: Unsupported SQL type 1111.
```

So I changed my mapping to following:

```
<parameter property="searchUserId" jdbcType="VARCHAR" javaType="java.lang.String" mode="IN"/>
```

which got rid of the error above, however, now the parameter `searchUserId` is getting value of `null` passed into the SP.  I know for sure that from my java code I am NOT passing `null`.

Has someone faced this issue? what should I change my mapping to??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameter element looks ok, after the change to use VARCHAR as jdbcType. Could you include the rest of the parameter element and the procedure element from the mapping file, and the code that creates the parameter map and calls the query?

It could be something simple like a typo when constructing the map passed into the query (at least that's the kind of mistake I would make -- I know I've been inconsistent about capitalizing "userId" while using Ibatis).

Comment: actually...in the process of me pasting rest of my code in the question i realized i DID have a type. searchUserId vs. searchUserID
>_< so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem for a different reason: The table had a `geometry` (PostGIS extension) column in it that I guess the driver couldn't parse. Dropping that column made it work.

Comment: question is, is there a way to still load the data by skipping that column rather than dropping it?

Answer (score 0):

I too faced a similar situation. After searching a lot, finally I found that  answer to my problem was that I was missing  a particular 'key' while constructing map. I was missing a statement:

```
map.put("job_name", job.getJobName());
```

& I was using JOB_NAME=#{job_name} in CronMapper.xml

Also some where else I was using JOB_NAME=#{jobName}

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is ancient, but 1 other thing to consider is does the value in the placeholder for iBatis (MyBatis) is null.  In my case, the error "JZ0SL: Unsupported SQL type 1111" was being thrown because the value being passed into the String parameter was null :

`<select id = "getInProcessDocsCount" parameterType="String" resultType ="int"> select count(*) from my_database..pub_wip_t where wip_stts_cde='IP' and rfrn_row = #{daemonID} </select>`

where #{daemonID} was null.  hth - adym